# Finding lower and upper limits of a function of four variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Is it possible to tell *Mathematica* to find the lower and upper limits of the following function

```
 fun[x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] = 
  1/2 (2 x1 (1 - y1) + 2 x2 (1 - y2) + x1 x2 (-2 + y1 + y2));
```

where $0\le x_1 \le 1$, $0\le x_2 \le 1$, $0\le y_1 \le 1$, and $0\le y_2 \le 1$.

Comment: See the documentation to `Maximize` /`Minimize`, especially the "Multivariate Problems" section to this end. E.g. `Maximize[{1/
    2* (2 x1 (1 - y1) + 2 x2 *(1 - y2) + x1 *x2 (-2 + y1 + y2)), 
  x1 >= 0 && x1 <= 1 && x2 <= 1 && x2 >= 0 && y1 >= 0 && y1 <= 1 && 
   y2 >= 0 && y2 <= 1},
 {x1, y1, x2, y2}]` does the job.

Comment: @user64494 - Also use `Map`, i.e.,  `#[{1/2*(2 x1 (1 - y1) + 2 x2*(1 - y2) + x1*x2 (-2 + y1 + y2)), x1 >= 0 && x1 <= 1 && x2 <= 1 && x2 >= 0 && y1 >= 0 && y1 <= 1 && y2 >= 0 && y2 <= 1}, {x1, y1, x2, y2}] & /@ {MinValue, MaxValue}` evaluates to `{0, 1}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`FunctionRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionRange) for this purpose:

```
FunctionRange[
    {fun[x1, x2, y1, y2], {x1, x2, y1, y2} ∈ Cuboid[{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}]},
    {x1, x2, y1, y2},
    z
]
```

> 0 <= z <= 1

Comment: I think `FunctionRange` uses `[N]Maximize` and `[N]Minimize` . E.g. `FunctionRange[      {(x1 + y2)^(Sqrt[2]*x2 + y1), {x1, x2, y1, y2} \[Element]     Cuboid[{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}]},      {x1, x2, y1, y2},      z  ] `performs `3.47791*10^-10 <= z <= 5.33029` and a warning

Comment: @user64494 `FunctionRange` does a bit more than just Maximize/Minimize, e.g., how does one just use Maximize/Minimize to do `FunctionRange[(x^2 - 1)/(x^2 - 2), x, y]`?

Comment: @CarlWool: Indeed, in this case the domain is split in intervals and then e.g. `FunctionRange[{(x^2 - 1)/(x^2 - 2), x < -Sqrt[2]}, x, y]` refers to `Minimize` and `Maximize`. Maybe, `FunctionContinuous` is used too.

Comment: In any case, `Maximize[(x^2 - 1)/(x^2 - 2), x]` together with `Minimize[(x^2 - 1)/(x^2 - 2), x]` answer the question about upper and lower limits.